# Move airdropped file from iCloud Downloads folder to our own app's folder

Tags: icloud, ios17, airdrop

in order to update the firmware of embedded device through my app, I need to **airdrop** the xml firmware file from my mac to my app which can be built in iPad and iPhone.

After receiving the file, under the hood of my app I could move the file from Documents folder to my own created Firmware folder. Then inside of my app, I could use the file which was then inside of Firmware folder.

But this flow is not working anymore after updating to **iOS 17**, as the airdropped file goes to **iCloud Downloads** folder and my parser function could not parse the contents/files inside of iCloud Downloads anymore.

Do I need to add some permissions to my info.plist to have access (read and move the file) to the content of that folder? Or is it even possible to manipulate the iCloud Downloads contents with the new changes in iOS 17? Does anyone else had the same issue of not knowing now, how to move the airdropped file from iCloud Downloads folder to another folder programmatically?

P.S1: this is the path of the url for iOS < 17: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/61C0294A-9372-434D-98DD-AFD3DB0FABEE/Documents/

And this is for iOS > 17:
file:///private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Downloads/